# Overflow error and need help to apply the same vba code to active worksheet in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a vba to multiply and divide between columns in the same worksheet.

Below is my code

```
Sub test1()
Dim i As Long
For i = 3 To 100
    Cells(i, 12) = (Cells(i, 8)) / (Cells(i, 6)) / 10 * 0.85
    Cells(i, 13) = (Cells(i, 9)) / (Cells(i, 6)) / 10 * 0.85   
Next i
End Sub
```

1. But I receive an `Overflow` error at 4th line of the code. Any advise?
2. Also I want the program to run for all active worksheet in the current workbook that I am currently working on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be getting an error as one of your dividing cells with be empty

In effect you are putting this formula in `L3:M100`
`=IF($F3<>"",(H3/$F3)/10*0.85,"")`

which can be done in all sheets as below

(you can record a macro to see how this formula should look in VBA)

```
Sub ReCut()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    With ws.Range("L3:M100")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC6<>"""",(RC[-4]/RC6)/10*0.85,"""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
Sub M_snb()
  [L3:M100] = [index(if(F3:F100="","",H3:I100/F3:F100/8.5),)]
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this

 Sub test1()
 Dim i, j As Integer
 Dim Ws As Worksheet
 For j = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
 Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j)
 For i = 3 To 100
    Ws.Cells(i, 12) = (Ws.Cells(i, 8)) / (Ws.Cells(i, 6)) / 10 * 0.85
    Ws.Cells(i, 13) = (Ws.Cells(i, 9)) / (Ws.Cells(i, 6)) / 10 * 0.85


Next i
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: doesnt address the overflow errror.